# whether the usage of NativeWebRequest is thread-safe or not

Tags: spring-boot

I want to know whether the usage of NativeWebRequest is thread-safe or not.
I'm confused that somebody said it is not thread-safe.
If you know something, thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is thread-safe. 
Spring controllers are indeed singletons (by default) that are called concurrently by multiple threads. But the request which is injected in the controller is not actually an HTTP request. 
BTW, at the time the controller is constructed, the server hasn't received any request yet. The request is in fact a proxy, which, whenever one of its methods is called, finds the current request being processed (by the current thread), and delegates to that request.